# Nginx увеличить таймаут для определенного URL

Tags: nginx, location

Необходимо отключить тайминг в 60 сек. для URL `/export/excel`

Для остальных сохранить дефотные найстройки таймингов

Есть конфигурация

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

   location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
      try_files /does_not_exists @php;
   }
}

location @php {
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
   try_files $uri =404;
   include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Добавляю:

```
location /export/excel {
   fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;
   proxy_connect_timeout       10;
   proxy_send_timeout          10;
   proxy_read_timeout          10;
   send_timeout                10;
   keepalive_timeout           10;
}
```

но так это не работает, подскажите как правильно?